# firebase functions fails to deploy on macos recently

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

all of a sudden my firebase functions have stopped deploying

the logs I see are below. i have tried deploying multiple times and upgrading packages etc but no luck. don't see anything useful in the logs either

```
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.810Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.812Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --only functions:divi_prices
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.812Z] CLI Version:   9.22.0
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.812Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.812Z] Node Version:  v14.17.0
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.819Z] Time:          Sun Nov 14 2021 18:54:01 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:54:01.819Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2xvdy1jaGVzcy1taXQvdXMtY2VudHJhbDEvZGl2aV9wcmljZXMvNndzU0tnb2VLbDQ {"name":"operations/c2xvdy1jaGVzcy1taXQvdXMtY2VudHJhbDEvZGl2aV9wcmljZXMvNndzU0tnb2VLbDQ","metadata":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.OperationMetadataV1","target":"projects/slow-chess-mit/locations/us-central1/functions/divi_prices","type":"UPDATE_FUNCTION","request":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunction","name":"projects/slow-chess-mit/locations/us-central1/functions/divi_prices","eventTrigger":{"eventType":"google.pubsub.topic.publish","resource":"projects/slow-chess-mit/topics/firebase-schedule-divi_prices-us-central1","service":"pubsub.googleapis.com","failurePolicy":{}},"status":"OFFLINE","entryPoint":"divi_prices","timeout":"60s","availableMemoryMb":256,"serviceAccountEmail":"slow-chess-mit@appspot.gserviceaccount.com","updateTime":"2021-11-14T04:51:50.789Z","versionId":"10","labels":{"deployment-scheduled":"true","deployment-tool":"cli-a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb":{"imageSizeBytes":"419002479","layerId":"","mediaType":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json","tag":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"],"timeCreatedMs":"315532801000","timeUploadedMs":"1636937698325"}},"name":"slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088","tags":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.179Z] Could not find image for function projects/slow-chess-mit/locations/us-central1/functions/on_game_finished_compute_highest_score
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.179Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list 200
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.179Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list {"child":["cache"],"manifest":{"sha256:998103042d58a26a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb":{"imageSizeBytes":"419002479","layerId":"","mediaType":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json","tag":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"],"timeCreatedMs":"315532801000","timeUploadedMs":"1636937698325"}},"name":"slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088","tags":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.179Z] Could not find image for function projects/slow-chess-mit/locations/us-central1/functions/on_token_audit_update_profile_coins
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.179Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list 200
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.179Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list {"child":["cache"],"manifest":{"sha256:998103042d58a26a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb":{"imageSizeBytes":"419002479","layerId":"","mediaType":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json","tag":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"],"timeCreatedMs":"315532801000","timeUploadedMs":"1636937698325"}},"name":"slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088","tags":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.180Z] Could not find image for function projects/slow-chess-mit/locations/us-central1/functions/on_user_created_update_user_count
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.180Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list 200
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.180Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list {"child":["cache"],"manifest":{"sha256:998103042d58a26a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb":{"imageSizeBytes":"419002479","layerId":"","mediaType":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json","tag":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"],"timeCreatedMs":"315532801000","timeUploadedMs":"1636937698325"}},"name":"slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088","tags":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.180Z] Could not find image for function projects/slow-chess-mit/locations/us-central1/functions/on_game_finished_update_game_type
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.181Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list 200
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.181Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/tags/list {"child":["cache"],"manifest":{"sha256:998103042d58a26a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb":{"imageSizeBytes":"419002479","layerId":"","mediaType":"application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json","tag":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"],"timeCreatedMs":"315532801000","timeUploadedMs":"1636937698325"}},"name":"slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088","tags":["divi_prices_version-11","latest"]}
[
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.364Z] <<< [apiv2][status] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/cache/manifests/latest 202
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.364Z] <<< [apiv2][body] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/cache/manifests/latest {"errors":[]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.365Z] >>> [apiv2][query] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/cache/manifests/sha256:df5c0e894e1e7998f9438f13f353878e17b7e7e69f30ec53d3d7da1e27c2d49c [none]
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.727Z] <<< [apiv2][status] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/cache/manifests/sha256:df5c0e894e1e7998f9438f13f353878e17b7e7e69f30ec53d3d7da1e27c2d49c 202
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.728Z] <<< [apiv2][body] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/cache/manifests/sha256:df5c0e894e1e7998f9438f13f353878e17b7e7e69f30ec53d3d7da1e27c2d49c {"errors":[]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.728Z] <<< [apiv2][status] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/manifests/sha256:998103042d58a26a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb 202
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.728Z] <<< [apiv2][body] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/slow-chess-mit/gcf/us-central1/e3f3ddb4-7b92-44c8-9b00-c66ac3023088/manifests/sha256:998103042d58a26a4fb043f92ee7c5e00683c2fe3f0f07240e7f3434fa08a4fb {"errors":[]}
[debug] [2021-11-15T00:55:24.832Z] Error: Failed to update function divi_prices in region us-central1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:38:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Fabricator.updateV1Function (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:250:32)
    at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:134:13)
    at async handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:75:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: well it fails for every function even hello world. does not look like a code specific issue

Comment: Following as I have the same issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any update / fix you were able to come up with?

Comment: look at my response below

Comment: Life-saver, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I decided to delete the latest function that i added and do a deploy for rest of the previously deployed unchanged functions in my index.ts. When i did that it gave me a warning that the new function that i added is not in my index.ts so should i delete that?

This means the error was kind of bogus and function actually got deployed. i headed over to the console and saw that function was indeed deployed though had some missing dependency error.

LEARNING: even with deployment showing failed with errors, do take a look at the firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and stumbled upon this Question. Though in my case running `yarn install` in the functions direction solved it. Apparently there was some mismatch with the `package.json` upon upgrading a package. Maybe this is useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is that I had both a `yarn.lock` and a `package-lock.json` in my `functions/` directory.

I deleted `yarn.lock` and ran `firebase deploy --only functions` again, which solved the problem.

The solution was revealed by looking at the cloud function logs in GCP console.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my `functions/package.json` contained the `script` `build`, which was executed while deploying. This build script errored and kept the function from deploying correctly. I think that executing this build script, if available, has been added by Firebase.

Locally I did not see the error. Saw it when checking the Cloud Console logs.